# Cross dissolve effect when using Stage Video

Tags: actionscript-3, video, air, stage3d

For performance reasons want to use the newer Stage Video class for hardware acceleration of video playback.

But I have 3 different videos that I need to 'cross dissolve' between, for a seamless transition.

Since Stage Video exists outside of the normal display list, not sure how I might achieve this.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: Stage Video instances do not support alpha channel, blend modes, filters, transforms, or masks.  You cannot bitmap cache nor nor use BitmapData.  Why not just crossfade within the video?

Comment: Trying to optimize performance. Doubt cross dissolving an HD or larger video will maintain an acceptable framerate